# Copy file, but error double free or corruption in C

Tags: c, gcc

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fe, *fs;
    unsigned char buffer[2048]; 
    int bytesreader;

    fe = fopen(argv[1], "rb"); 

    fs = fopen(argv[2], "wb"); 


    while((bytesreader = fread(buffer, 1, 2048, fe)))
       fwrite(buffer, 1, bytesreader, fs);

    fclose(fe);
    fclose(fs);
    return 0;
}
```

And my error is...

```
*** glibc detected *** ./doc2: double free or corruption (top): 0x096b7008 ***
```

Sorry, now is correct, but i dont undertand. Where is my fail?

Comment: What is `bytesLeidos`?

Comment: naughty to have argv[1] etc. without checking value of argc

Comment: Also naughty not to check the result of fopen

Comment: int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fe, *fs;
    unsigned char buffer[2048]; 
    int bytesreader;

    fe = fopen(argv[1], "rb"); 

    fs = fopen(argv[2], "wb"); 


    while((bytesreader = fread(buffer, 1, 2048, fe)))
       fwrite(buffer, 1, bytesreader, fs);

    fclose(fe);
    fclose(fs);
    return 0;
}

Comment: Sorry, bytesLeidos = bytesreader

Comment: @Vicky: Better update your question with the actual code, rather then stuffing it into a comment.

Answer (score 6):

You need to check the return values of fopen() for 0.

Calling fclose() on 0 results in the error you are seeing.

Also, check argc for a valid range of arguments.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fe, *fs;
    unsigned char buffer[2048]; 
    int bytesreader;

    if(argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s file1 file2\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    fe = fopen(argv[1], "rb"); 
    if(fe == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Failed to open %s for read\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    fs = fopen(argv[2], "wb"); 
    if(fs == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Failed to open %s for write\n", argv[0], argv[2]);
        exit(1);
    }


    while((bytesreader = fread(buffer, 1, 2048, fe)))
       fwrite(buffer, 1, bytesreader, fs);

    fclose(fe);
    fclose(fs);
    return 0;
}
```