# Dividing a file into equal parts of 128 bytes each

Tags: c, file, gcc, divide

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fe, *fs;
    unsigned char buffer[128];
    int bytesreader;
    int i;
    char cad[100];

    fe = fopen("pg2000.txt", "rb");
    fseek(fe, 0L, SEEK_END);
    int x = ftell(fe);
    printf("%d",x);
    int x = ftell(fe);
    int result=x/128;

    for(i=0;i<result;i++)
    {
        bytesreader = fread(buffer, 1, 128, fe)
        sprintf(cad, "a%d", i);
        strcat(cad,".txt");
        printf("%s\n", cad);
        fs = fopen(cad, "wb");
        fwrite(buffer, 1, bytesreader, fs);
        fclose(fs);
    }

    fclose(fe);

    return 0;
}
```

I want to split a file into equal parts of 128 bytes each, but when the file is large I get a access violation, I don't understand...

Comment: I guess you didn't learn your lesson about checking fopen's return value. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213006/copy-file-but-error-double-free-or-corruption-in-c

Comment: Likewise for `ftell`, which will happily return 0 since you're at the beginning of the file. And `fs` should really be closed ***inside*** the for loop, since that is where you opened it.

Comment: I I made changes, but still does not work

Answer (score 3):

```
fe = fopen("pg2000.txt", "rb"); 
int x = ftell(fe);
int result=x/128;
```

`x` here will be zero. If the `fopen()` suceeds. Which you need to check for.

Also, as WhozCraig points out, the `fclose()` for `fs` should be inside your loop.

And this

```
for(i=0;i=result;i++)
         ^
```

Is probably not exactly what you had in mind either.

Comment: Because fe is pointing to the end of the file after that seek? Maybe seek back to the beginning or use rewind.